# Restore Mint logon screen

Tags: linux-mint, login

I'm using Mint 17.1.  Yesterday I uninstalled `cowsay` and `fortune` as I never use them; `fortune` had dependencies that were also removed, I assumed because they were no longer needed.  However, on shutting down yesterday I briefly saw an Ubuntu 14.04 screen but assumed it was just a little glitch.  Today, on booting up, instead of getting my lovely Mint log on screen, I get an unfamiliar blue log on screen.

I'm guessing this must be as a result of uninstalling those dependencies.  I half hope I'm wrong because if that's not the cause, then I've got other issues.

So I suppose I have two questions:

1. How can I restore my minty log on screen?
2. And for future reference, how can I be sure when I uninstall something that its dependencies really aren't needed any more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered `/var/log/apt/history.log` and found the following entry to do with removing `fortunes`:

```
Start-Date: 2015-02-09  09:54:18
Remove: mint-artwork-gnome:amd64 (2.6.36), fortunes-husse:amd64 (1.0.2), mint-meta-cinnamon:amd64 (2014.12.09), mint-meta-core:amd64 (2014.12.09), fortune-mod:amd64 (1.99.1-7), mint-artwork-common:amd64 (1.8.4), mintsystem:amd64 (7.9.7+1), ubuntu-system-adjustments:amd64 (2014.11.19)
End-Date: 2015-02-09  09:54:29[/code]
```

So the simple fix was to reinstall the non-`fortunes` stuff:

```
sudo apt-get install mint-artwork-gnome mint-meta-cinnamon mint-meta-core mint-artwork-common mintsystem ubuntu-system-adjustments
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same kind of problem (with Mint 13 LTS), but do not remember exactly for what cause, and find no way to fix it.  I try to reinstall lot of package, but nothing works.  Sorry, I do not take note of all the actions.

As a workaround, on the login screen, I log in as root, then type 'mdm', and that start -let's say- normally the login screen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I actually solved my issue already (see my answer), but perhaps your comments will help someone else!

Comment: Ok happy for you !   I try your 'installs', but it does not fix my problem. So mine is another specie :(